# Get promise data from angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Hey i'm trying to build some default validation for $http promises. The reason i do this is because i have multiple requests that return the same result structure. so it would be logical to seperate the handler from the request to reduce code duplicates

Let's say i have this request:

```
    getMoreUsers: function(searchid, apiroute, limit) {
        console.log(apiroute);
        return $http({
            method: 'get', 
            url: WeAlertApiUrl + apiroute,
            params: {
                'searchid' : searchid,
                'start' : limit }
        }).then( function(data) {
           if(data.data.isValid === true) {
              return processUsers(data.data.users);
           }else {
              $cordovaToast.showShortTop(data.data.message).then(function(success) {
              }, function (error) {alert(data.data.message);});
           }
        }, function(error) {
            $cordovaToast.showShortTop("something went wrong..").then(function(success) {
            }, function (error) {alert("Something went wrong..");});
        }); 
    },
```

The only thing that isn't consistent is `data.data.users`
so ideally i'd like to construct something like this:

```
getMoreUsers: function(searchid, apiroute, limit) {
        console.log(apiroute);
        return $http({
            method: 'get', 
            url: WeAlertApiUrl + apiroute,
            params: {
                'searchid' : searchid,
                'start' : limit }
        }).then( 
           return handleResult(processUsers(data.data.users))
        }); 
    },
```

Is this achievable? and how do i access the promise of $http and send it to a service

Thanks to @Bergi i was able to solve it! 
the getmoreusers service now looks like

```
    getMoreUsers: function(searchid, apiroute, limit) {
        console.log(apiroute);
        return $http({
            method: 'get', 
            url: WeAlertApiUrl + apiroute,
            params: {
                'searchid' : searchid,
                'start' : limit }
        }).then(function(res){return successHandler(res, 'users');}, errorHandler);
    },
```

and the success and error handlers are wrapped like :

```
.factory('successHandler', function($cordovaToast, processAlerts, processUsers, processBerichten, processReacties, processUserAlerts) {
        return function(data, type) {
            if(data.data.isValid === true){
                switch(type){
                    case 'users':
                        return processUsers(data.data[type]);
                    case 'alerts':  
                        return processAlerts(data.data[type]);
                    case 'berichten':   
                        return processBerichten(data.data[type]);
                    case 'reacties':    
                        return processReacties(data.data[type]);
                    case 'useralerts':  
                        return processUserAlerts(data.data[type]);              
                }
            }else {
                $cordovaToast.showShortTop(data.data.message).then(function(success) {
                }, function (error) {alert(data.data.message);});
            }   
        };
    }).factory('errorHandler', function($cordovaToast) {
        return function(error) {
            $cordovaToast.showShortTop("Er ging iets mis... bent u verbonden met het internet?").then(function(success) {
            }, function (error) {
                alert("Er ging iets mis... bent u verbonden met het internet?");
            });
        };
    })
```

Comment: this is called transformResponse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, returning `data.data.users` is totally fine. You'll want to `return` the promise for the processed data, so that your callers can consume them like

```
getMoreUsers(…).then(handleResult);
```

For that, the global error handlers should also rethrow the exceptions

```
getMoreUsers: function(searchid, apiroute, limit) {
    console.log(apiroute);
    return $http({
        method: 'get', 
        url: WeAlertApiUrl + apiroute,
        params: {
            'searchid' : searchid,
            'start' : limit }
    }).then(function(data) {
        if (data.data.isValid) {
            return processUsers(data.data.users);
        } else {
            throw new Error(data.data.message);
        }
    }, function(error) {
        throw new Error("something went wrong.."); // ignore `error` details
    }).catch(function(error) {
        $cordovaToast.showShortTop(error.message).catch(function(showError) {
            alert(error.message);
        });
        throw error;
    }); 
},
```

Comment: but why should I do this per request and not make a promiseHandler for it? most of this code will be used around 20 times why add 20 lines when you could invoke the same function with a single line??

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit: I thought `handleResult` would be different for every request?

Comment: If it's the same handler every time, then `return handleResult(processUsers(data.data.users))` should just work.

Comment: Yes, but how would i pass the promise of $http to handleResult like handleResult($promise) or something?

Comment: What are you doing in `handleResult` that you would need to promise? Don't you want to use the result of `processUsers()`?

Comment: well .then returns a promise right? so i would like to use that promise in handle result for success and error. i'm now trying to use seperate succes and error callbacks within then but i'm still not getting the data into the success callback `.then(successHandler(success, 'users'),errorHandler(error));`

Comment: You must not call the handlers but pass them, so `.then(successHandler, errorHandler)` or `.then(function(res){return successHandler(res, 'users');}, errorHandler)` would work.